# Small complete categories in a Grothendieck topos

Tags: ct.category-theory, topos-theory

It is a classical theorem of Freyd that if a small category is complete (has all small limits—in fact, having small products suffices), then it is a preorder (has at most one morphism between any two objects).  The proof of this theorem (which can be found [here](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/adjoint+functor+theorem) or in CWM) is non-constructive, i.e. it uses the Law of Excluded Middle.  Therefore, it can potentially fail in the internal logic of an elementary topos.  And in fact, it *does* fail in the effective topos, and more generally in realizability topoi, where there do exist small complete categories that are not preorders.

However, I have heard it said that Freyd's theorem cannot fail in a *Grothendieck* topos; i.e. that a small complete category in a Grothendieck topos must still be a preorder—despite the fact that the internal logic is still in general intuitionistic, so that Freyd's proof cannot work.  Can someone explain why this is, or (even better) give a reference containing a proof?

Comment: Good question. Since Grothendieck toposes are complete for higher-order intuitionistic logic we cannot hope to produce an internal argument. We have to use something about Grothendieck toposes, presumably cocompleteness.

Comment: The question can be reduced easily to the following. In a Grothendieck topos, suppose we have a mono $m : A \to B$ such that, for every object $I$, there is a mono $A^I \to B$. What can $A$ be? In $\mathsf{Set}$ it has to be empty or a singleton.

Comment: What do you mean formally for  "internal complete category"?

I find some different definitions about indexed categories (Sketches of an Elephant I, or Indexed Categories and their Applications, LNM 661).

I formulate another one in terms of Kan extentions in the 2-cetegory of  internal categories.


How completeness is definible in the internal topos  logic ?.
this definition agree with the definitions of completeness of a indexed category?

Excuse me for the mistakes and for the bad English, and thank for your time.

Comment: @Buschi, the paper "The Discrete Objects in the Effective Topos" has a fairly exhaustive discussion of the relevant notions of "completeness" for internal categories, in the context of showing that such categories do exist in the effective topos.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Hi.  I mentioned that I had thought about this on nForum a while back - sorry I didn't get back to you sooner.  The following sketch of a proof is mainly due to Colin McLarty.

Two features which distinguish a Grothendieck topos from a more general topos are

1. That it has a geometric morphism to Sets, namely the global sections functor.
2. That it has an object of generators (i.e. there is an object G such that if $f,g: A \to B$ are not equal then there exists an arrow $h: G \to A$  with $fh \neq gh$)

Let $C$ be a small complete category object in a Grothendieck topos $T$ which is not a preorder.  Then $C^G$ is also a small complete category in this topos essentially because exponentials commute.  The global sections functor applied to $C^G$ gives a small complete category in the category of sets which is not a preorder (the property of being a small complete category is preserved by geometric morphisms, and the special property of G allows the property of being "not a preorder" to carry through), which is a contradiction.

It is a little easier to think about in the case of sheaves on some topological space.  There a small complete category object which is not a preorder would have to fail to be a preorder on some open set, and the sections on that open set would be a small complete category which is not a preorder.  $G$ takes the place of this open set above.

If you have any questions about this let me know.  In particular I can write out all of the adjunctions showing various properties are preserved, but I don't want to get too nitty gritty if it isn't useful to you.

Kind regards,
Steven Gubkin

Comment: Thanks!!  Does that proof really use boundedness (the existence of G)?  If T is any Set-topos containing a small complete category C, then the adjunction argument seems to say that $\Gamma(C^G)$ is a small complete category in Set for any object G, hence a preorder; and thus the category T(G,C) is a preorder for any object G of T.  Which should imply that C is a preorder in the internal logic of T, via Kripke-Joyal semantics.

Comment: Also, it appears that the only property of Set used is that it is Boolean.  If so, then something stronger is true: no topos which admits a (possibly bounded) geometric morphism to any Boolean topos can contain a small complete category.
