# Can there be a small complete category in ZF?

Tags: ct.category-theory, set-theory, lo.logic

It's a [ZFC theorem of Freyd](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/complete+small+category), any small complete category is a preorder. Freyd's theorem continues to hold [in any Grothendieck topos](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/43433/small-complete-categories-in-a-grothendieck-topos). But Hyland showed it fails [in some elementary toposes](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/complete+small+category#in_more_general_toposes_and_constructive_mathematics).

I don't actually know, but I suspect that Hyland's topos examples don't readily translate into models of ZF — toposes don't play well with replacement. So

**Question:** Does Freyd's theorem hold in ZF?

That is, in ZF is every small complete category a preorder?

Comment: [An article by Claire Kouwenhoven-Gentil and Jaap van Oosten](https://www.jstor.org/stable/27588398) gives a way how to construct a model of IZF, an intuitionistic version of ZF, from the effective topos. So I think the problematic part is not Replacement. (To be fair, however, their construction uses an inaccessible cardinal.)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes, Freyd's theorem holds in ZF. The theorem relies on excluded middle, choice does not play a role. Just to be sure, let's work with excluded middle but without choice.

**Theorem:** *A small-complete small category is a preorder.*

*Proof.* Let $C$ be a small-complete small category, with $C_0$ the set of objects and $C_1$ the set of morphisms. Consider any $x, y \in C_0$. We need to show that the set of morphisms $C(x,y)$ contains at most one element. For this purpose, suppose $r_0 : x \to y$ and $r_1 : x \to y$. By excluded middle it suffices to show that $r_0 \neq r_1$ leads to a contradiction. So assume $r_0 \neq r_1$, and define $z = \prod_{C_1} y$, the $C_1$-fold product of $y$'s. Note that a morphism $h : x \to z$ is given as a $C_1$-indexed family $h = \langle h_f \rangle_{f \in C_1}$ of morphisms $h_f : x \to y$.

Define the map $i : \{0,1\}^{C_1} \to C_1$ by
$$i(c) = \langle r_{c(f)}\rangle_{f \in C_1} : x \to z.$$
we claim that $i$ is injective, which is impossible because it would give us a surjection $C_1 \to \{0,1\}^{C_1}$ by excluded middle, contradicting Cantor's theorem (which is constructive). To see that $i$ is injective, suppose $i(c) = i(d)$. Then $r_{c(f)} = r_{d(f)}$ for all $f \in C_1$, but since $r_0 \neq r_1$ it follows that $c(f) = d(f)$ for all $f \in C_1$ (no excluded middle here because equality on $\{0,1\}$ is decidable), hence $c = d$. $\Box$

In the above proof there two applications of excluded middle: concluding $r_0 = r_1$ from $\lnot\lnot (r_0 = r_1)$, and obtaining a surjection $C_1 \to \{0,1\}^{C_1}$ from an injection $\{0,1\}^{C_1} \to C_1$. As far as I can tell, both are necessary. And we never used choice.

Comment: Also note we never used replacement, the proof works in any Boolean topos.